# Associated Values in SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a value in database say A0001 and it has associated values in other columns such as B001, C001 and D001.

I want to create a query saying whenever a value from above three 'B001,C001 and D001' is found then return me A0001. This is just an example but all values are starting with 'A' and have different numbers.

Out results might look like this: When A like are found it return col2 as below:

```
Col 1     Col 2
A0001     BOO1,C001, D001
```

They are associated and have many such A numbered values and many associated values in other column.

Please help thanks

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: It is not a good idea to have three values separated by commas in the same column. You should use different columns or another table to do it

Comment: Please add table definition and sample data as text to the question.

Comment: I echo @nacho it's a **really bad idea**. Use tables as they are meant to be, one value per column/row, with foreign keys

Comment: Don't spam the tags. MySQL and SQL Server are very different and use different sql dialects and offer different functionality.

Comment: @nacho They are linked values and in SQL database they have been assiciated with a main account which lies in other column. Myquestion is how to search and returnthose single values.

Comment: I will explain again what I am trying to do here: Col 1 has values like B001/1 C001/2 and Col 2 has value such as B001. I am trying to merge both tables to get values for Col 2. But there is one issue in Col 1 one of the value is D001/3 which is S LIke in Col2. Not sure how to merge both. I need some help with Substring function. I tried one but then lost second part.